# Hive table creation error through Bash Shell

Tags: hadoop, hive, partitioning, ddl, hiveql

Can anyone give me why I am getting error while creating partitioed table from bash shell.

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ hive -e "create table peoplecountry (
name1 string,
name2 string,
salary int,
country string
) 
partitioned by (country string)
row format delimited
column terminated by '\n'";

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-0.10.0-cdh4.7.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Hive history file=/tmp/cloudera/hive_job_log_0fdf7083-8ab4-499f-8048-a85f162d1357_376056456.txt
FAILED: ParseException line 8:0 missing EOF at 'column' near 'delimited'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant newline at end of each row of your data then you need to use:

```
     line terminated by '\n'
```

instead of column terminated by ,

In case you meant each column in the row to separated by a delimiter , then specify as

```
    fields terminated by '\n'
```

refer :

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL